# How to recognise blank spaces using regular expressions

Tags: php, preg-replace, regular-language

how would I extend this preg_replace (in PHP), using regular expressions to replace white spaces also..

```
$this->permalink = preg_replace('[^a-z0-9]', '-', $this->permalink);
```

It's for generating page permalinks based on a page title. 'About me' will become 'about-me'. everything's fine except it doesn't remove the space yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, you should probably try a quick regex tutorial. This is really basic stuff.

Comment: You could change your regex to `[^a-z0-9]|\s`, but your above expression works for me.

Comment: That didn't work. '|' broke the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, you're regular expression is missing the delimiters. I've also added the `i` modifier so that it's case-insensitive.

**Example:**

```
$this->permalink = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '-', $this->permalink);
```

Here's a working example: http://codepad.org/OlzQax1c.

Comment: This is still wrong. His regex will remove spaces, but he's missing the `/` delimiters.

Comment: @coreyward - You're absolutely correct. I've corrected my answer and added the `i` modifier too. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex coady - It does. I misunderstood your question but copy the line above and try it again.

Comment: Cheers @francois - I can't accept yours as the right answer for another 6 minutes though...

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$this->permalink = preg_replace('/\W/i', '-', $this->permalink);
```

`\W` is any non-word character (letter, number, underscore)